# How can I retrieve the base and inferred statements (subject, predicate, object) from an ontology?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I am using the Quran ontolology from http://quranontology.com/Concept. I am using jena for this purpose
I am getting null and some strange values in the statements so far. This is what I am getting.

```
null    subClassOf     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
null    type     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class
Verse    subClassOf     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
Verse    type     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class
null    subClassOf     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
null    type     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class
subject    type     http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property
subject    domain     http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Statement
subject    subPropertyOf     http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#subject
Literal    type     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class
Literal    subClassOf     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
Location    subClassOf     http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
SecondBlow    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
BrothersOfYusuf    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Lut    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Ayyub    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Al-Safa    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Cain    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Harun    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Wolf    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Passing-the-Sirat    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Yusuf    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Bani-Nadir-Houses    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Elephant    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
Children-of-Israel    type     5ca31608:152fab841db:-7fe2
```

**Note: I do not want the URI to be included in the output only the names are required.**

The code I am running is;

```
String fileName = "quran.owl";  
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM_RDFS_INF);                
            model.read(reader, null);
            Iterator iter = model.listStatements();                       
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Statement state = (Statement) iter.next();
                if (state != null) {                   
                    System.out.println(state.getSubject().getLocalName() + "    " + 
                            state.getPredicate().getLocalName() 
                            + "     " + state.getObject().toString()
                    );
                }
            }          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're trying to achieve and what you don't understand about the code you posted? If you want to extract specific data like names, there is a [public SPARQL endpoint](http://quranontology.com/Query) you can use.

Comment: I want the triple statements from jena. And also what is the best way to use the reasoner to get all inferred and basic statements. The result I am expecting is a list of statements containing <subject, predicate, object>.
I am familiar with SPARQL endpoint, if I get the SPARQL query for this that would help too.

Comment: Your code does print triples. Not sure what the question is. As for inference: It would help if you edited your question to explain what you're trying to achieve, data-wise. Re SPARQL: The predefined query in the endpoint I linked is a good starting point.

Comment: You get null when the subject is  blank node and so does not have a local name (which is part of the URI).

Answer (score 0):

You get null when the subject is not a blank node, not a URI.

Block nodes don't have a URI and so don't have a local name (which is part of the URI).